# ConstraintLayout and RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, keyboard, android-manifest, android-constraintlayout

I am using constraint layout and inside it I have RecyclerView.
Whenever keyboard is opened, it resizes the window, but RecyclerView is not scrolled to correct item.

All other solutions I found were not working or it was to code logic yourself. Usually with just "always scroll to bottom" which is also not acceptable.

**View hirearchy**

```
ConstraintLayout
    TextView (topToParent)
    RecyclerView (topToBottomOf TextView, bottomToTopOf EditText)
    EditText (bottomToParent)
```

**Manifest**

```
<activity 
    android:name=".ChatActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
/>
```

Is there some solution I didn't find?

P.S.: `adjustPan` works, but it's not precisely wanted behavior.

//Edit: Non-programming solution preferred.

Comment: Rewritten it back to relative layout which is working fine. So either I dont understand constraintLayout enough or it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It your view contains only RecyclerView i will advise you to add

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

To your activity in AndroidManifest.xml file. It will block ui to jump when keyboard appears.

Comment: unfortunately, it is not the only one.. my bad for making question too compact